# lookup() возвращает NULL

Tags: excel

Проблема в том, что функция `lookup()` не выводит соответствующее значение (ячейка `J3`):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но почему-то по соседнему ключу - все работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Значения в `I2:I4` - список из диапазона `A:A`,`B:B`, `C:C` соответственно.

Comment: дак может пусто в соответствующей ячейке просто?

Comment: Да нет, стоит же значение 1860..

Comment: а действительно. А почему  на второй картинке цена от другой материнки выводится? выбрана 350я   а показывается от 250й?

Comment: вообще лучше бы вы `ВПР` (`VLOOKUP`) использовали. там хоть можно настроить точное совпадение и индекс столбца

Comment: в общем юзайте `=ВПР($I$3, C:D; 2; ЛОЖЬ)`

Comment: Неправильно закрепили ссылки: *=ВПР(I3;$C$2:$D$500;2;)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно справке Microsoft Excel

> Для правильной работы функции ПРОСМОТР(LOOKUP) просматриваемые данные должны быть отсортированы в возрастающем порядке.

У Вас же сортировка отсутствует. Формула находит строку, которая в сортировке должна быть ниже искомой, и прекращает поиск. Решений может быть 2, либо Вы сортируете список по возрастанию, либо, опять же согласно справке,

> Если это невозможно, рекомендуется использовать функции ВПР(VLOOKUP), ГПР(HLOOKUP) или ПОИСКПОЗ(MATCH).

Comment: хах, прочитал ведь в справке про сортировку, и не обратил внимания на данные из вопроса :)

Answer (score 1):

Функция *LOOKUP (ПРОСМОТР)* не умеет определять диапазон пользовательских данных. Если указывать полные диапазоны строк/столбцов, то она будет лопатить эти диапазоны полностью (а это существенно, если искомых данных нет в диапазоне). Правильнее  ограничивать диапазоны.

Сортировать диапазон не обязательно:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/($C$2:$C$500=I2);$D$2:$D$500)
```

Функция создает массив, состящий из единиц и ошибок (*#ДЕЛ/0!*). В этом массиве производится поиск числа 2, которое больше максимального в диапазоне. Такого нет и функция определит позицию последнего значения (ошибки игнорируются). На этой позиции находится нужное значение столбца *D*